# How to put a PHP 'not null' condition on mysql insert statement?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I have a page with two forms on it (and two submit buttons), and the forms link the page back to *itself* with action="" for the INSERT INTO statements. One of the INSERT INTO statements is:

```
<?php
$sql="INSERT INTO panelProduct (length_mm, width_mm, aperture)

VALUES ('$_POST[p_length_mm]','$_POST[p_width_mm]','$_POST[p_aperture]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
?>
```

One of the reasons I have put the form and the INSERT statements on the same page is that the form allows users to add products to an order, and there may be several products (so I thought the user could keep submitting until they're done...). The other reason was that I need to use a $_POST value sent from the previous page to do something else with the products they enter, and I don't know how to send it to more than one page.

Anyway, the problem I have found is that a new row is inserted into the database every time the page is refreshed, containing NULL values. This makes sense to me as the PHP will execute the statement above every time it encounters it. My question therefore is how I can make some sort of condition that will only execute the INSERT statement if the user enters something in the form and 'Submits'?

Comment: This has been mentioned before in your other questions ... please stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: @Jack, the 08/15 scaremongering with an abundance of links for people who don't frequent the manual anyway has no effect? Surprising.

Comment: @mario perhaps ... how about every time you use mysql_ God kills a kitten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the empty() method of PHP to check for null values in each of the variables.

Something like:

```
if(!empty($_POST['p_length_mm']) && !empty($_POST['p_width_mm']) && !empty($_POST['p_aperture']))
{
//execute your query here
}
else
{
//if there's an alternative you would like to happen if values are null, or just leave out.
}
```

Hope that does the trick.

Comment: please read "Why $foo[bar] is wrong" chapter of PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar

Comment: Glad to hear it, don't forget to accept the answer when you're done.

Matt.

Answer (score 1):

You need a condition like this:

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    // a form was posted
}
```

Of course, you still need to check whether your post actually contains the right stuff:

```
isset($_POST['p_length_mm'], $_POST['p_width_mm'], $_POST['p_aperture'])
```

Even better is to use [`filter_input_array()`](http://www.php.net/filter_input_array) to sanitize your incoming data; your current code is open to SQL injection attacks. Using `PDO` or `mysqli` and prepared statements is the way to go.

Comment: this is wrong approach. because you test request method which may not mean form was posted or, more common, that form was posted. If you got more forms you'd have to have separate action for each, instead of one with some conditions to find out which one was the poster

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com Fair enough, I've added some more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if data come from your form. I'd suggest this approach - name your submit button (i.e. `<input type="submit" name="my_submit_button" value="Whatever" />` and this condition to your insert code:

```
if( isset( $_POST['my_submit_button']) ) {
  .. process your post data
}
```

Also, always remember not to trust user provided data. Verify if all data expected are present in`$_POST` and format matches requirements (i.e. you ask for number and received letters etc). If all test passed, then you are ready to commit your data to DB.